# Precision-Recall curve for multiple target scores

Tags: python, scikit-learn, precision-recall, amazon-rekognition

AWS Rekognition [CompareFaces API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/APIReference/API_CompareFaces.html#API_CompareFaces_ResponseSyntax) return the response like this:

```json
{
   "FaceMatches": [ 
      { 
         "Face": {
            ...
            "Confidence": number,
            ...
         },
         "Similarity": number
      }
   ],
   "SourceImageFace": { 
      ...
      "Confidence": number,
      ...
   },
   ...
}
```

where `Confidence` predicts that an image region is a face and `Similarity` predicts that two faces belong to the same person.

What would be the best way to calculate a precision-recall curve incorporating both these scores? So then I can decide to use, for instance, `Confidence` threshold of any face >= 99% and `Similarity` threshold >= 80%.